# Authenticity token not changing in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authenticity-token

My application is built using rails 3 and i have added the csrf_meta_tag in application.html.erb.

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Authenticity token is changing for different users, but the token is same in the entire session i.e its not changing for each put & post request.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you accidentally cache it?

Comment: That they it works Authenticity token stays same for the entire session. it does not changes for every request as a copy of authenticity in encrypted form is mapped in with your cookies which is used to match against whether the authenticity token is valid or not

Comment: @anil.n Just set session[:csrf_token]=nil if you want it to change for every request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authenticity token stays same for the entire session. it does not changes   for every request as a copy of authenticity in encrypted form is mapped in with your cookies which is used to match against whether the authenticity token is valid or not

Just set `session[:csrf_token]=nil` if you want it to change for every request

Just cross check this I know this work but done it long back

Also just check if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744459/rails-csrf-tokens-do-they-expire) for more info