# Rails 4 expired CSRF token after some time

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I have Rails 4 app.
Yesterday, if I had opened a page with a form and my computer stays awake, the next day when I try to submit the form app returns:

```
500 Internal Error
```

The log says that authenticity_token is invalid. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method of the form that you are submitting, you could place something like:

```
if response.status == "500"
  redirect_to "enter a suitable url here"
  raise "Your token has expired."
end
```

This is an extremely basic solution. If it does not work for you there is a nice question and accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744459/rails-csrf-tokens-do-they-expire) that you can read up on.