# random ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

There is random CSRF errors on my app with `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`. Like, one out of 100 requests or more. Why would those errors appears randomly like this?

I got them on some regular `<%= form_with %>` tag, some on javascript post (but it works most of the time because I add the `meta[name='csrf-token']` as `X-CSRF-TOKEN` every time), some on `devise/registrations#create`, etc...

Why would it happen sometimes and not every time?

Regards

Comment: do you serve https ?

Comment: @DileepNandanam yes tls 1.2, everything is working fine most of the time for everybody, juste randomly sometimes it is not working. Maybe the token is invalidated somewhere.

Comment: see if you have proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; in location section.

Comment: no :/ but thanks for helping

Comment: try to add that before doing a pry on requests

Comment: Do you experience yourself these errors, or do you see them in logs from real users ?

Comment: @colinux can't reproduce, real users

Answer (score 3):

A CSRF token will expire when a Rails session expire (except for some configurations).

#### Here is a scenario raising this error :

If an user has a form displayed on a page, go away for a few dozen of minutes (depends of session duration), and comes back filling the form, the session (and token) may have expired. Then at submission Rails will raises `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

More about that here [Rails CSRF Tokens - Do they expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744459/rails-csrf-tokens-do-they-expire)

Another scenario involves (bad) bots : a bot could submit the form without using the token.