# Rails 6 CSRF Token Expiry issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf, csrf-token

We are encountering an issue with form submission in production environment.
The criteria seems to be exceptionally rare, I have been unable to replicate the issue.

CSRF token is created and validated just fine.

#### Timing

Issue seems to occur only when users wait more than 2 hours on a form before submitting, but doing this we have been unable to reproduce as well.
Logs

```
W, [2022-07-14T15:19:37.535241 #2433]  WARN -- : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
I, [2022-07-14T15:19:37.535556 #2433]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 291)
F, [2022-07-14T15:19:37.536425 #2433] FATAL -- :   
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

#### System configuration

**Rails version 6.1.6**
**Ruby version 2.7.4**

Comment: What do you mean by _"CSRF token is created and validated just fine"_? Do you mean it works in general or is the token that causes the error known to be valid at some point?

Comment: Both of them actually. In this particular example, I had the user submit a log in request with this token, that succeeded and then later he submitted another form that caused invalid error.

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7744459/477037 (_"users sit on the real-time page for a long time. Every now and then the user gets kicked out"_). Maybe your sessions / cookies expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by `rails-ujs` failing to insert CSRF token alongside remote form submissions in some cases.

I was not able to identify the root cause but an upgrade to Rails 7 and [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check in your initializers for a session_store.rb

Inside if it you may find an expire_after is already set:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                       key: '_myapp_session_',
                                       expire_after: 30.minutes
```

Comment: That isn't it, There is no expiry set on the session_store. ```Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  key: 'my_app_session',
  domain: :all,
  same_site: :strict,
  secure: !Rails.env.development?
}```

Comment: Well if it's not coming from the cookie then I am confused.  I would recommend you change your production logger to DEBUG so you can see all of the information such as the EXACT USER having the issue.  It sounds like some kind of minor bug although it could also be a cache problem on the customers or users part too.  I have had bad cache cause this before, is it just one customer or many you said userS so I assume more than one?

Comment: This article goes into a deep dive, maybe it will trigger a thought on your app.  https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you so much for the help almost a year ago now. I was at least able to track the issue down to `rails-ujs` replacing it with `turbo-rails` worked. As a bonus the app also runs better now and Dev experience has improved too.